# Conditional Auto-Numbering in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, conditional

I want to replicate the excel "Countif" funcion in Sharepoint Site for Conditional Auto-Numbering of the list getting generated.
e.g.
Input Required Output
A        A-1
B        B-1
C        C-1
A        A-2
B        B-2
C        C-2
A        A-3
B        B-3
C        C-3

It should lookup the input existing in old entries for increment the counter.

I'm using Sharepoint 3.0 site and machine is installed with 2007 designer, 2010 Infopath, 2010 Sharepoint.
Plz help.

Comment: Didn't understand the environment details. It's confusing.How can you use SP 3.0 site with SP 2010 infra?

Comment: The Sharepoint 2003 page can be hosted using Ms Sharepoint Developer 2007...
Can I expect the required solution from your end Sir...